# How to add WHERE criteria to joinedload()?

Tags: sqlalchemy

The section "Adding Criteria to loader options" of the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html#adding-criteria-to-loader-options) seems to cover this use case, but it is very terse and I just don't understand it. In particular I have no idea what the `A.bs.and_()` is supposed to accomplish. I want to do a joinedload() of a Parent/Child relationship but only where the child's name is 'Eric' (see example below). My points:

1. What is it that I don't understand about "Adding Criteria to loader options?" Am I even looking in the right part of the manual?
2. I know how to do a normal JOIN but I don't want to have all parents and children in one result set. I want to iterate over parents and children in nested loops. The problem is simple to solve in less time that it took to prepare this post, but I want to know if SQLAlchemy can help me here.
3. I have noticed the `with_loader_criteria()` reference, I have tried it, and it works, but I understand the documentation even less.
4. Whatever the final solution may be -- is there anything resembling it in v1.3? I may have to deal with some legacy code that can't be upgraded yet (but I hope to be able to avoid that).

Sample code below.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, joinedload
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    name = Column(String(20))
    parent = relationship('Parent', back_populates='children')

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship('Child', back_populates='parent')


def print_statement(query):
    print (query.statement
           .compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))

engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
db = sessionmaker(engine)()

parent = Parent()
db.add(parent)
parent.children.append(Child(name="Eric"))
parent.children.append(Child(name="Emmy"))
db.commit()

q = (db.query(Parent)
     .options(joinedload(Parent.children,
                         Child.name == 'Eric', innerjoin=True)))

print_statement(q)
```

The resulting statement ignores the `Child.name == 'Eric'` criteria:

```
SELECT parent.id, child_1.id AS id_1, child_1.parent_id, child_1.name
FROM parent JOIN child AS child_1 ON parent.id = child_1.parent_id
```

Comment: `joinedload(Parent.children.and_(Child.name == 'Eric'), innerjoin=True)` is what you want (the `and_` adds the criterion to the join).  It doesn't exist in 1.3 though, you need >= 1.4.